# Adjacent components css files are conflicting with each other in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using react to create a website and in one of my child components I am importing a css file for a cute animation. The problem is that this is causing conflicts across all of my pages (this is a single page application). All of my styling has been moved around, even pages without the imported stylesheet. Its quite a bit of code so I deployed it on heroku so you guys can have a look: https://farm-management-pro.herokuapp.com

You can sign in with "e@e.com" with password of "e" or make an account with any valid email string.

Answer (score 0):

Use [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) package. This allows you to avoid conflicts.

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    background: blue;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase
`

const MyAwesomeComponent = props => (
    <StyledButton>This is my awesome button<StyledButton>
)

export default MyAwesomeComponent
```

This allows you to isolate your styles in each of your components, thus preventing conflicts.

Read more [here](https://www.styled-components.com/docs)